# DSInit has disappeared on upgrading Azure SDK to 2.3

Tags: sdk, azure-storage

I recently upgraded two separate development environments to the new Azure SDK 2.3 tools.

The storage emulator did not initialise as expected. So I go to run DSinit to initialise the database and it's gone! It's like someone has stolen it. I have searched the whole disk and it's not there. So now I have a storage emulator that will not initialise and the tool to repair it has somehow disappeared when I upgraded from Azure SDK 2.2 to 2.3.

The question is, Where can I get DSInit. and Is this just me?

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling both SDK's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like DSInit is no longer the way to start the emulator.

The options I can see is to use [CSRun](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg433001.aspx) from an Azure SDK Command Prompt

```
    csrun /devstore:start
```

This appears to have been replaced by WAStorageEmulator.exe that can be found at %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Storage Emulator. From there, WAStorageEmulator.exe can be run to init, start and stop the emulator.

```
WAStorageEmulator.exe init            : Initialize the emulator database and configuration.
WAStorageEmulator.exe start           : Start the emulator.
WAStorageEmulator.exe stop            : Stop the emulator.
WAStorageEmulator.exe status          : Get current emulator status.
WAStorageEmulator.exe clear           : Delete all data in the emulator.
WAStorageEmulator.exe help [command]  : Show general or command-specific help.
```

There is also an icon on the Start Menu/Screen that runs WAStorageEmulator.exe for you in a command prompt.

Comment: thanks... I somehow got around the issue by using: SqlLocalDB start v11.0      Although I'm not sure why it worked. I'll go look at WASStorageEmulator.EXE now...

Answer (score 0):

DSInit is replaced by WAStorageEmulator. You can run the following commands in Windows Azure Command Prompt - 2.3:

Change the directory:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Storage Emulator
```

Running the utility:

```
WAStorageEmulator init /sqlInstance .\sqlexpress
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Update for SDK 2.7.1: Path is now "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe"